# How to stop a user from even listing a directory in linux?

Tags: permissions

I know I can `chown <user> <dir>` but the user2 can still `ls` it. How do I stop user2 from even listing or `ls` the directory?

Comment: Useful links: (0) [`chmod`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). (1) [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/108618). (2) [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/108618) (3) [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13858/108618) (4) Mind [this behavior](https://superuser.com/q/1584668/432690).

Comment: I think I figured it out. I need to `chmod 755` the dir after `chown`ing it.