# Linux user is in group but does not have group permissions

Tags: linux, debian

I have this folder with these permissions:

```
jessie@services1:~$ ls -lisa /srv/
total 12
  1769 4 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Nov  5 20:42 .    
     2 4 drwxr-xr-x 18 root root   4096 Oct 28 11:43 ..   
386699 4 drw-rw----  2 root docker 4096 Nov 17 20:03 vault
```

If I am correct I should be able to access the `vault` directory when I am in the group `docker`.

```
jessie@services1:~$ groups
jessie sudo www-data docker
jessie@services1:~$ id
uid=1000(jessie) gid=1001(jessie) groups=1001(jessie),27(sudo),33(www-data),998(docker)
```

But when I try to access the folder I get a permission denied

```
jessie@services1:~$ cat /srv/vault/docker-compose.yml 
cat: /srv/vault/docker-compose.yml: Permission denied
```

The permissions inside are also correct (I think):

```
root@services1:/home/jessie# ls -lisa /srv/vault/
total 12
386699 4 drw-rw---- 2 root docker 4096 Nov 17 20:03 .
  1769 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Nov  5 20:42 ..
389900 4 -rw-rw---- 1 root docker  424 Nov 17 20:03 docker-compose.yml
```

Machine OS: Debian 10

I have tried logging out and back in but nothing seems to work. Do any of you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your second `ls` is run as root. Could it be that you're unable to list the content of the directory with your regular user? You could be missing the [x bit on the directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 386699 4 drw-rw----  2 root docker 4096 Nov 17 20:03 vault
> ```

No `x` in `rw-rw----` for `vault` indicates the directory is not executable for anyone. [The root user is not denied access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412234/108618) though, regular users are.

You need the `x` bit to access files inside the directory. See:

- [*Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/108618)
- [*Do I really need recursive `chmod` to restrict access to a folder?*](https://superuser.com/q/1425574/432690)

`chmod g+x vault` is what you need. The resulting permissions will be `rw-rwx---`. It's somewhat unusual to have `x` for the owning group and not for the owning user; but since the owner is `root`, it won't matter much in this case.

In general (i.e. when the owner is not necessarily root) `rwxrwx---` makes more sense than `rw-rwx---`, unless the owner has a reason to restrict access for himself. Note the owning user's permissions matter for the owner [even if he's in the owning group](https://superuser.com/q/1584668/432690).

Comment: `x` means _searchable_ rather than _executable_ for directories