# Permissions depend on from where the command is executed

Tags: permissions, external-drive

I have encountered a very strange behaviour I do not know how to solve: the action permissions depend on where the command is executed.

My situation: I set up a Nextcloud server on a Raspberry Pi 4. The system works off of an SD card and the Nextcloud instance is on an SSD, run via Docker (using IOTstack). As far as Nextcloud is concerned, everything works as expected.

When I want to list the contents of the Nextcloud instance, I may use the root account as such:

```
sudo ls -lh /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4K Nov  3 11:09  Documents
```

Of course, this works because of `root`. When I try the normal account `pi` then I get the following:

```
ls -lh /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
ls: cannot access '/media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files': Permission denied
```

That's because everything belongs to `www-data`, so I try as `www-data` and I get:

```
sudo -u www-data ls -lh /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
ls: cannot access '/media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files': Permission denied
```

This is not normal... I should be able to see the files of the user they belong to.

I tried to `cd` to the mounted SSD (`storage`) and execute the command again:

```
cd /media/pi/storage/
sudo -u www-data ls -lh ./IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4K Nov  3 11:09  Documents
```

Why? How come the permissions depend on from where the `ls` command is executed? Why can I list the files from `/media/pi/storage` and not from `/home/pi`, as the `www-data` user? Should `www-data` be in the `pi` group?

Previously I had the data stored on the SD card, under `/home/pi/IOTstack...`, but I wanted to store my files in a more safe location, while keeping the option of swapping the hardware. I did not encounter this issue.

The reason for accessing files in this "raw" way is to back them up over the network to another storage media.

---

**Edit**

Answering @kamil-maciorowski

```
namei -nom /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
f: /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
 drwxr-xr-x root     root /
 drwxr-xr-x root     root media
 drwxr-x--- pi       pi   pi
 drwxr-xr-x pi       pi   storage
 drwxr-xr-x pi       pi   IOTstack
 drwxr-xr-x pi       pi   volumes
 drwxr-xr-x pi       pi   nextcloud
 drwxrwx--- www-data root html
                          data - Permission denied
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of [`namei -nom /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24143/108618).

Comment: I edited the question and added the output of the command you gave. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful links:

- [*Do I really need recursive `chmod` to restrict access to a folder?*](https://superuser.com/a/1425631/432690)

  > So if you remove […] both read and execute privileges on a directory, anything below it becomes unreachable […].
- [Pathname resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13)

When you do

```
ls -lh /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
```

as `pi`, the pathname is resolved, `/`, `media`, `pi`, `storage`, `IOTstack`, `volumes`, and `nextcloud` can be accessed. Then the procedure comes to the `html` component. The ownership and mode of `html` are `www-data:root` and `drwxrwx---` respectively. When you are `pi` (which is neither `www-data` nor in the `root` group), [the last triplet applies](https://superuser.com/a/1584678/432690), it's `---`. This means you cannot access `html`, `data` and further pathname components.

When you do

```
ls -lh /media/pi/storage/IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
```

as `www-data`, the pathname is resolved, `/` and `media` can be accessed. Then the procedure comes to the `pi` component. The ownership and mode of `pi` are `pi:pi` and `rwxr-x---` respectively. When you are `www-data` (which is neither `pi` nor in the `pi` group), the last triplet applies, it's `---`. This means you cannot access `pi`, `storage` and further pathname components.

You said "this is not normal", but the mechanism of access denial is the same as in the first try; the only difference is the pathname component being the culprit: `html` or `pi`. Both cases are equally normal.

When you `cd /media/pi/storage/` as `pi`, you can do this because the modes for all the relevant directories allow you to.

When you *then* run

```
ls -lh ./IOTstack/volumes/nextcloud/html/data/solenoid/files
```

as `www-data`, the mode of `/media/pi` is irrelevant because pathname resolution starts from `.`: `.`, `IOTstack`, `volumes` and so on. It so happens `www-data` can access all these [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) and thus `ls` works.

In other words `cd` performed as `pi` puts you under the very component `www-data` cannot access. Then `pi` becomes `www-data` thanks to `sudo`, but the working directory does not change. The path given to `ls` starts from `.`, not from `/`, it can now be resolved and accessed. Note if you used the full path (i.e. starting from `/`, like in the previous tries), then it still couldn't be accessed, regardless of the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful to understand path resolution. In the end, I used `sudo` to traverse the whole thing as needed.